How to apply a condition over a vector in R
i need to a particular type of substitution, infact i want to replace some blanks (" " characters) in a data frame with a random choice on the same column, given a certain condition (for example i sample another value for a certain patient)
I wrote three lines of code that work, but when i put them in a function the function doesn't work (i need to create a function in order to use apply).
the dataset (df) has this structure
Name var1 var2 var3
1  John 1    Br   5
2  John 3    " "  6
2  Frank 2   Rt  7
3  Ryan 3    Rt   8

for every name there is a repetition for each observation typically, suppose i want to replace the element in position (2,3).
Then i wrote the function
sub_blanks <- function(x,y){
tiny_dataset <- df[df$Name == df$Name[x]]
value <- df[sample(1:length(tiny_dataset$Name),t] 
df[x,t] <- value
}

but the function doesn't works

This question is similar to: Vector creation and modification based on other vectors. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Using replace
set.seed(1)

nblnk <- sum(df$var2 == " ")

replace(df$var2, df$var2 == " ", sample(df$var2[df$var2 != " "], nblnk))
[1] "Br" "Br" "Rt" "Rt"

on the data frame
set.seed(1)

nblnk <- sum(df$var2 == " ")

df$var2 <- 
  replace(df$var2, df$var2 == " ", sample(df$var2[df$var2 != " "], nblnk))

df
   Name var1 var2 var3
1  John    1   Br    5
2  John    3   Br    6
3 Frank    2   Rt    7
4  Ryan    3   Rt    8

